# Not able to query RoleInTerritory2 field from UserTerritory2Association in Apex class

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I want to query the RoleInTerritory2 field from UserTerritory2Association  sObject. I am logged in as System Admin profile but still not able to query this field. Starnge thing here is that I am able to query this via developer console. Does anyone have any idea reagrding it? 
It gives me an error :
No such column 'RoleInTerritory2' on entity 'UserTerritory2Association'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the problem. There was an API version conflict. It works for API versions 30 above.

Comment: The class where I was trying to use UserTerritory2Association object, was of API version 30 which doesn't support it. I changed the API version for the class that solved my issue.

Comment: Would you mind specifying which API version you changed it to? I tried this and it didn't solve my problem.